# typo3 felogin to custom controller?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I want to bind the felogin-mask to a controller in one of my extensions, because I have a custom login process.

The idea is that the user types his data to the form, submits it and my controller handles the rest.

Is such a thing possible? Or should I do it in another way?

Comment: TYPO3 offers hooks "afterLogin": Google TYPO3 "Hooks" and "Signal Slots"

Comment: But I want to completly handle the login process on my own. Thats why I also asked if I should do it in another way. I'm never completly sure how to use a typo3-function because the documentation is so bad and outdated.

Comment: Stuffy: Then copy the felogin extension and adjust it to your needs. (Or create your own from scratch). How to create new extensions and edit them: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/latest/ExtensionArchitecture/Index.html

Comment: Thanks, that was my original idea. So I'm just going to not use felogin at all and just build everything on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate the sending of credentials and the actual login process. The [TYPO3 Service Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/Typo3ServicesReference/Authentication/Index.html) recently got an update describing the login process and all involved services.

In short, you need to create an own authentication service. An example can be found in the `openid` extension that now lives on `TER` (used to be a system extension).

You can still use the frontend login extension to send the credentials or create the form on your own. I suggest to dig into the authentication process first. There you will find all required details.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Definitely will have a look at that.